# Why there is no output showing in this YouTube crawler in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

youtube = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" 

def get_address(keyword): 
    query = youtube + keyword 
    source_code = requests.get(query) 
    plain_text = source_code.text 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser") 

    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'id': 'video-title'}): 
        href = link.get('href') 
        print(href)
        break

get_address("scishow")
```

The program runs successfully, but instead of showing the address of the video, it shows nothing in the output.

Comment: Your code is fine, the only reason it doesn't show anything in the output is because the `a` tag that you're looking for is not there. The `<a id="video-title" ...>` is added to the page later with JavaScript, which of course hasn't been executed when you retrieve the initial HTML code.

Comment: Most probably because the page is using `JS`. Request will be useless in this case, use `selenium` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube is running heavily on javascript. I suggest you use selenium. Here's your updated code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

youtube = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="

def get_address(keyword):
    query = youtube + keyword
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(query)
    plain_text = browser.page_source
    browser.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'id': 'video-title'}):
       href = link.get('href')
       print(href)

get_address("scishow")
```